# Keeping dropdown menu active (visible) even after mouse out using animation or transition property in CSS

Tags: html, css

My menu disappears immediately after I move my mouse pointer outside menu div. I want that menu to stay active. I have tried similar ways but could not achieve what I need. Please point out where I have made the mistake. Here is the HTML & CSS code for your reference done in JsFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/adhiyan_c/p7g4suwb/

```
I need the dropdown to be made visible for 2 seconds even after mouse out.
```

Comment: just use setTimeout for 2 seconds after mouse out of  menu div.

Comment: is it possible do it through transition or animation property in css rather than using Jquery. @ArashYounesi

Comment: it will be easy using jquery bro..

Comment: I think no.jquery is more simple to do this

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp
http://jsfiddle.net/jeffreyTang/q5cmqLrf/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this in your jQuery..

```
$(".vdropdown").mouseover(function(){
 $(".vdropdown-content").show();

});
$(".vdropdown").mouseout(function(){
 $(".vdropdown-content").hide(2000);

});
```

this will do instead of using css

Comment: you could also use jquery hover()